# AspectMock doesn't appear to be mocking static methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, codeception

I am new to aspectmock as I need to find a way to mock static method calls (no way of changing the app, it's not really written well for testing, and it's huge)

Here is my bootstrap:

```
<?php
include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; // composer autoload

$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__.'/../src'] // <-- not really sure what this ought to be
]);
```

Here is my test

```
<?php
use AspectMock\Test as AspectMock;

class YoutubeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        AspectMock::clean(); // remove all registered test doubles
    }

    public function testDoubleClass()
    {
        $youtube = new JT_Cron_Youtube(null, array());

        $videomodel = AspectMock::double('ACQ_Model_VideoQueue', ['save' => null]);
        \ACQ_Model_Videoqueue::count();
        \ACQ_Model_Videoqueue::count();
        $videomodel->verifyInvokedMultipleTimes('count', 2);
    }
}
```

..however, it is still giving me errors that would indicate that the static methods are not being mocked. I'm not really sure how AspectMock does it's magic, I just took this from the documentation:

https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

Is there anything I'm not doing correctly, or misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've observed, the source files that you are creating doubles for must be listed in the *includePaths* config.

In your case, ensure the folder containing the code for *ACQ_Model_VideoQueue* is added.